# pandas combine row and column to single column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in pandas and I'm having the following dataframe:

|  | column_A | column_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row_1 | X1 | Y1 |
| row_2 | X2 | Y2 |

and I want to change it in the following format:

| column_A_row1 | column_B_row1 | column_A_row2 | column_B_row2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | Y1 | X2 | Y2 |

Is there an easy way to do this in pandas (or any other way) ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with convert to one row DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
print (df)
  column_A_row_1 column_B_row_1 column_A_row_2 column_B_row_2
0             X1             Y1             X2             Y2
```